# How do I delete labels from the billing UI in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, billing

In Google Cloud Platform, you can add labels to several resources and also *add labels to the query jobs you execute*. I did this second option. A typical code looks like this:

```
bq query --label=my_label:{parameter} --label=my_label2:{parameter2} --format=json --use_legacy_sql=false '{query}'"
```

But, by mistake, the first time I did like this:

```
bq query --label=my_label{parameter} --label=my_label2:{parameter2} --format=json --use_legacy_sql=false '{query}'"
```

which created several jobs (I regularly ran this command) having a label named `my_labelFoo` with an empty value instead of a label named `my_label` with a value of `Foo`. This was detected when, in the Billing UI, we noticed several labels as options for filtering, being all of them:

my_labelFoo
my_labelBar
my_labelBaz
my_labelJohn
my_labelGeorge
my_labelRingo
my_labelPaul
...

What I tried to do, then, is to delete the metadata of those wrong jobs. So I tried this query in BigQuery (having the appropriate permissions):

```
SELECT job_id, query, labels FROM `my-project`.`region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(labels) > 0 AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM UNNEST(labels) l WHERE l.key = 'my_labelRingo')"
```

For each `job_id` retrieved this way, I tried invoking:

```
from google.cloud.bigquery import Client
Client().delete_job_metadata(job_id, location="us")
```

What I can say for good, is that the job entries were removed (they were a few amount), but...

...when I go back to the Billing UI, **I still see the my_labelRingo as a selectable label from there**. I don't want that label to exist anymore.

So, my question is:

- How do I delete the wrong labels from the Billing UI?
- Is there, perhaps, a time I have to wait for `my_labelRingo` to cease to exist?

Comment: By saying Billing UI, do you mean GCP Console > Billing?

Comment: Yes. The billing console.

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but take a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery-tables/standard-usage#differences_between_exported_data_and_invoices).

Answer (score 0):

The situation you are experiencing with the labels in the Billing console is something specific to Cloud Billing Support and you will need to directly engage them using [this link](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing/)
so they can fully investigate why it is happening.

**The solutions shared below are different alternatives to delete labels in the GCP BigQuery console.**

You can delete a table or view label in the following ways:

1. Using the console
2. Using SQL DDL statements
3. Using the bq command-line tool's bq update command
4. Calling the tables.patch API method

- Because views are treated like table resources, tables.patch is used to modify both views and tables.

5. Using the client libraries

But you would need to have the next permissions:

- bigquery.tables.get
- bigquery.tables.update

For example to delete a label through  the console you need to follow the next steps:

1. On the console, select the dataset you want to edit.
2. Click on the details tab and then click the pencil icon to the right of labels.

[image]

3. On the edit labels dialog

- For each label you want to delete, click delete (X)

[image]

- Click on update to save the changes,

Also you can see [more ways](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/deleting-labels#deleting_a_table_or_view_label_2) to delete labels.